# In Wordpress, Is there a way to reference a custom post types custom field data?

Tags: wordpress

Inside of the functions.php file, is there a way to get a custom post types custom field data? I'm would like to know what the data is depending on any post id that is passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$id = YOUR_POST_ID;
$meta = get_post_meta($id, 'custom_field_name', true);
echo $meta;
?>
```